# How to join tables selecting both matched and unmatched records?

Tags: sql, join

I have tables that do a count of a certain action for different days.  I am trying to join those tables to show each type of action and the count for each day.  If the action happened on both days its fine.  But if I have an action that only happened on day one or only on day two, I would like those as well.

I have tried different types of joins and unions and can not seem to get it to show the expect results.

In table 1 and 2 I have first four columns that match based on the pl & sta(the two fields I want to join on)  so I should get the count from both tables as shown in the outcome.  However table 1 has one that is 414 - 1PL with a count of 26 and table 2 has 41M - 2PL with a count of 12.  I would like each of those that are unmatching returned in the pl and sta fields with the count of each one under that column for that days count.

Table data:

```
Table 1
pl  | sta | count_1
----+-----+--------
410 | 1PL |    7777
410 | MPL |      31
412 | 1PL |      67
412 | 3PL |       1
414 | 1PL |      26
```

```
Table 2
pl  | sta | count_2
----+-----+--------
410 | 1PL |    7000
410 | MPL |      26
412 | 1PL |      52
412 | 3PL |       1
41M | 2PL |      12
```

```
Outcome
pl  | sta | count_1 | count_2
----+-----+---------+--------
410 | 1PL |    7777 |    7000
410 | MPL |      31 |      26
412 | 1PL |      67 |      52
412 | 3PL |       1 |       1
414 | 1PL |      26 |       0
41M | 2PL |       0 |      12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a full join and coalesce:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.pl, t2.pl) AS pl
    , COALESCE(t1.sta, t2.sta) AS sta
    , COALESCE(t1.count_1, 0) AS count_1
    , COALESCE(t2.count_2, 0) AS count_2
FROM t1
FULL JOIN t2 ON t1.pl = t2.pl AND COALESCE(t1.sta, -99) = COALESCE(t2.sta, -99)
```

In order to account for cases where sta is NULL, replace sta with -99 or some other value that is otherwise invalid.

Comment: This works as I need for 99% of the cases.  I have some where the pl will have an entry and the sta will be blank.  This is causing me to have multirple rows of those. 
For Example:

`997   <NULL>   1   0   0
997   <NULL>   0   1   0
997   <NULL>   0   0   1`

Where I would expect it to be all in one row as   997   <NULL>   1   1   1

Comment: Try now... You can account for those in the join condition using another coalesce

Answer (score 0):

You can try FULL OUTER JOIN
example :

SELECT * FROM tableA FULL OUTER JOIN tableB ON tableA.pl =tableB.pl

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you can write this using a `full join`.  In doing so, I recommend the `using` clause:

```
select pl, sta,
       coalesce(t1.count_1, 0) as count_1,
       coalesce(t2.count_2, 0) as count_2
from t1 full join
     t2
     on t1.pl = t2.pl and t1.sta = t2.sta;
```

Most, but not all databases, support `using`.

You can also write this as a `union all`/`group by`:

```
select pl, sta, sum(count_1) as count_1, sum(count_2) as count_2
from ((select pl, sta, count_1, 0 as count_2
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select pl, sta, 0, count_2
       from t2
      )
     ) t2
group by pl, sta;
```

This is useful under some circumstances:

- If you have multiple rows per `pl`/`sta` in either table.
- If either `pl` or `sta` could ever be `NULL`.
- If you have an aversion to using `COALESCE()`.  (That is a joke).